# Problem with receiving message from server in socket programming UDP

Tags: c, sockets

I have the task to create a code in C with 3 servers and one client. After the start of the client, it should indefinitely listen on the port for notifications of the arrival of a new server.

I came up with code that the server will send a hello message, and when the client receives the message, it will add the server to the list of known servers. But the client does not receive it at all.

Client logic:

```c
int bytes_received = recvfrom(client_socket, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);

if (bytes_received == -1) {
    printf("ERROR: %s (%s:%d)\n", strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(-1);
}

buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';

if (strncmp(buffer, "HELLO: ", 7) == 0) {
    
    char *content = buffer + 7;  
    printf("Received HELLO message from server: %s\n", content);
    printf("Received HELLO message from (%s:%d): %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port), buffer + 1);
    if (num_known_servers < MAX_SERVERS) {
        struct Server new_server;
        memcpy(&new_server.addr, (struct sockaddr_in *)(&client_addr), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        new_server.last_message_time = time(NULL);
        known_servers[num_known_servers++] = new_server;
        char log_message[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        snprintf(log_message, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, "New server discovered at %s:%d", inet_ntoa(new_server.addr.sin_addr), ntohs(new_server.addr.sin_port));
        logMessage(log_message);
    }
} else if {
  continue;
}
```

Server logic:

```c
char server_message[] = "HELLO: Hello from server";
            
if (sendto(server_socket, server_message, strlen(server_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr)) == -1) {
    printf("ERROR: %s (%s:%d)\n", strerror(errno), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: `(struct sockaddr_in *)(&client_addr)` This is a fishy cast. What type is `client_addr` declared as?

Comment: Also `strlen(server_message)` looks like a bug, should be `strlen(server_message)+1`. Or if you will: `sizeof(server_message)`.

Comment: `else if { continue }` ==> Did you mean `else { continue }`?

Comment: Please post a proper [mre].

Comment: How sockets are created? How `client_socket` is bound to socket address? How `client_addr` is initialized?

Comment: Did you verify with a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, that the hello message is actually being transmitted by the server machine and is being received by the client machine? Is the server really sending the hello directly to the client itself, or is the server broadcasting to the subnet that the client is attached to?